# How to detect to which branch a tagged commit was merged into

Tags: git, continuous-integration, git-merge, git-tag

As part of a ci process I have, which is triggered by git tags, I need to auto-update something in the code, using that tag name, and then commit the result back to git.

Problem is, after a successful merge request, the branch is usually deleted, so the tag for that commit, is now completely detached and is not contained within any branch, so "commiting back to git" is not so trivial, because I don't have a branch to commit into.

I can commit by default into master, and that will usually work, but there will be edge cases in which I cannot predict the behavior for.

A more reasonable solution, is to somehow (if possible) figure out to which branch a tagged commit was merged into, so that I'll commit back to that branch.

Is that possible?

(also, if you see any problems with this approach and/or have something better to suggest, please share your thoughts)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of branches from which the tag is reachable

```
git for-each-ref --contains my_tag refs/heads
```

(You could use `git branch` instead of `git for-each-ref`, but `for-each-ref` is generally better suited to use in a script.  You might have to add a `--format` option to get the output looking the way you want.)

This could return multiple branches, and you'd have to decide how to reconcile that.  One strategy would be to see if one of the branches is reachable from the other.  For example if you have

```
x -- x -- A <-[my_tag]
            \
         ... M -- x <--(b1)
                   \
                ... M <--(b2)
```

we have `b1` reachable from `b2` and the tagged commit reachable by both.  You might intuitively prefer to say that `A` was merged into `b1`, if "what merge command do I think was issued" is the important thing.  Or, if it works better to commit near the newest development, maybe you'd choose `b2` in that case.  Either way, you also could encounter a case like

```
x -- x -- A <-[my_tag]
            \
             \        x <--(b1)
              \      /
           ... M -- x
                     \
                      x <--(b2)
```

where it's totally arbitrary to say that `A` was merged "into `b1`" vs "into `b2`" (vs. "into some other branch that no longer exists").  So at this point, you might have to just pick one.

So speaking generally, you cannot uniquely identify one branch into which the tagged commit was merged.  It may have been merged into a branch that's been deleted, or it may have even been merged in detached HEAD state.

You might be able to eliminate some of those possibilities due to your knowledge of the team's branch/merge strategy and other practices, but it's worth noting that git itself doesn't *care* about concepts like "branch into which this commit was merged" - it only cares about things like "branches that, in the current state, can reach this commit"; so you have to impose assumptions to be more specific.